# Recommendation for very lightweight website framework

Tags: python, mercurial, sinatra, nancy

I want to update/rewrite a small (10 page), simple website; 8 pages are entirely static and could be written in html, 1 page has a contact form and the other has to display a filterable list of clubs. At the moment the site is written in classic asp and uses dreamweaver templates for consistent pages.

My requirements are

1. A "masterpage" / Templating system, so all shared page elements are written in only 1 place.
2. Lightweight / low overhead framework
3. To learn a new language

I could use ASP.NET Webforms or ASP.NET MVC to get the masterpage, but they both come with overhead that isn't necessary for such a small site and on my godaddy hosting spinning up a site from cold is noticeably slower than a pure html page.

The clubs page will show a list of clubs filterable by location, but I don't want to use a database to store this list - there is another site that has the official list of clubs, but the system isn't capable of providing this as a service or other consumable resource so I would need to scrape the details periodically and cache them locally or use an iframe or something

I thought maybe Python or django might be good candidates but don't know enough to know. I now think that what I'm looking for is a "micro web framework". I've taken a quick look at the [Mercurial Web Server](http://www.the-wombat-speaks.co.uk/blog/post/2011/03/31/setting-mercurial-18-server-iis7-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) which is written in python and that looks quite straightforward, but I don't have access to the hosted web server on Go Daddy, so can't install python...

**Edit**
I need this to run on my current shared hosting with GoDaddy on (IIS7)

**Edit2**
The list of clubs is maintained by the official HQ website, they occasionally add / remove clubs. I just need to keep my list up to date with theirs. I have been checking every few months (if I remember) and updating an MS SQL database, but that's hugely over the top. I was thinking of just pulling the details down into a json format and persisting it in a text file (once a month, or something) which I could then use as the basis of a table with jQuery filtering on. The club details are just text; Name of Club, Main contact, phone number, address and email address.

I would also like publishing to be simple, commit the code to Mercurial (or git) and have that run the site. I know bitbucket (and github) both serve static page sites (I'm not sure how I would get a contact us form to work in that environment - but it's the deployment model I would like)

The site I am looking to update is [Seika Dojo](http://www.seikadojo.co.uk/)

Comment: What did you end up using ? (There seem to be very lightweight mammoths out there.)

Comment: I've gone down the path of xml, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703312/including-an-xml-file-in-an-xml-xsl-file?lq=1, this gives me the really simple includes that I wanted without any overhead on the server. So it's _almost_ as good as static html, the very minor dynamic content is being pulled in with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know about the other frameworks, but I have good experiences building a small site in NancyFx.

1. NancyFx supports multiple view engines. You could use the SuperSimpleViewEngine; [masterpages come out of the box](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-engines).
2. [Getting started with Nancy is super easy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Introduction).
3. I think you already know .NET/C#, but Nancy takes a lot of advantage of new dynamic features which are fun to play with.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to run monsters to serve 10 almost static pages. If you plan to pull and cache some data out of the web, it is a way to go to update static HTML.

As another author mentioned HTML5 can help you. Take a look at jQuery for [table filtration](http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm). As for page regeneration with common elements consider either [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)/[hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) or [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) (using batch processing mode with emacs). You have a plenty of languages to choose from.

Comment: I don't fancy the idea of batch processing to create templated layout, but definitely will use some jQuery to filter the list of clubs rather than use a database. +1 for "There is no need to run monsters to server 10 almost static pages" I am definitely trying to avoid running a monster just to get templated pages.

Comment: Think of batch processing as of extremely effective caching:-) It would make sense to run something dynamic, if you were fetching live data from somewhere. However you said that you need to _scrape the details periodically and cache them locally_. So that is it. I, personally, was considering Plone (as I used it before) before switching to org-mode for my needs. Different needs, different solutions.

Comment: Put like that _"extremely effective caching"_... that does make sense. It seems a bit like the Dreamweaver templates that the site currently uses though and I'd like to get away from that a bit. Include files that define a menu, footer or header I'm fine with, but for 10 pages I _could_ copy/paste (shudder) the shared layout.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dreamweaver. Does it allow some scripting to pull external content as you'd like to generate those static pages? I might be wrong but it seems like it only offers client & server side scripting for dynamic pages and not static. Those few tools I've mentioned provide more than simple templating. Ruby/python/elisp(+anything else) are at your disposal.

Comment: Dreamweaver defines regions of a template that you can edit in content pages and locks out others (as long as you're using Dreamweaver to edit). If you change something in the shared portion of the template page then you can update all the pages that use the template... in essence it sounds like batch processing - dwt files require Dreamweaver and I _think_ org-mode requires it's tool is installed to work

Answer (score 1):

Python is my favorite language, but I wouldn't use it for creating a simple website. I would recommend you to go with ready made CMS solutions, like Wordpress.

- You would learn something new.
- You won't have to implement any features (CMS + plug-ins will provide all you need).
- You will get all the support you need.
- It is easy to deploy on any hosting (since it's PHP based -yeap, sorry, php-).

Comment: A CMS is way more than I'm looking for, page content doesn't need versioning / updating and I'm happy to just edit the html and publish (ideally committing to a mercurial (or git) repo to deploy)

Answer (score 1):

Cactus:

https://github.com/koenbok/Cactus

is my current favourite static site generator - it uses Django templates to create a set of pages (in the 'build' directory) from a set of templates (in the 'pages' directory) and all the usual images and css in a 'static' directory.

Do your filterable table with Javascript on the client - it doesn't sound too complex. This lovely table grid component:

http://datatables.net/

might be just the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

[Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/) wasn't mentioned. It produces static pages and is done in Python. It meets all of the stated criteria.

Comment: I should also have mentioned [Complexity](http://complexity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/readme.html) because it specifically supports `json` files.

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks and play with a couple of the choices that tickle your fancy.  I would tend toward the lighter frameworks based on what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) or [webpy](http://webpy.org/)? They are very minimalist, python web frameworks designed for something like this. (I think django is too big for this small of an app, IMHO)

Also, take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you want to learn some ruby.

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is good for some javascript experience.

For single-page apps, [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) is popular and really powerful, but might not be what you want.

But most importantly, have fun learning a new language!

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly on the topic, since you don't need entirely static website, [StaticMatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/)
may be of interest as one of the best lightweight tools for static content generation.

Answer (score 0):

Flask and web.py would both be good choices. I don't think that Django is really suited for such a small project but you can definitely use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking around further and the goal of a templating system can be met by just using [xml includes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703613/96505), or [Embedded JavaScript](http://embeddedjs.com/) to pull in the header / footer / menu sections. All the 'work' is then done on the client browser, so the web server only needs to serve up static files which is about as lightweight as you can get.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience, any 8 page static website someday needs dynamic features so it is always a good idea to start from something extensible.

Then the first decision is to use a Framework or a CMS. This depends on your expectation of the site getting bigger in the future, your ability to develop custom codes to achieve dynamic features and the structure and the requirements of the project in hand.

When we need a CMS we use,

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) if ASP .NET MVC 3: Take a look at our site [www.dreamrain.com](http://www.dreamrain.com) which looks like a static website but actually uses Orchard themes and modules for the dynamic features. If you don't need themes and modules, you can still create a 8 page website and then you can extend it in the future. Btw, we built this site in 5 days with 4 hours of development effort

Note: Orchard may need Full Trust so check its documentation and ask GoDaddy if they allow it.

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) if PHP,

When we need a Framework we use,

ASP .NET MVC 3  for .NET,
[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Pyramid](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org) for Python,
[Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) for PHP, 
[Grails](http://grails.org/) for Groovy/Java/J2EE,
[Play](http://www.playframework.org/) for SCALA

Comment: In most cases I would agree that having a CMS would make sense - however I have been running the site since 2001 and I **know** it will not need dynamic features. I've used Orchard quite a bit (and WP occasionally) but honestly the overheads in these are not right for this very simple site

Comment: As I told in my answer, that overhead is just 4 hours of development for a low complexity website, an ASP .NET MVC 3 hosting and a bit of hardware. This is always better than changing a typo in a page by getting, updating and uploading an html page through ftp.

Comment: It isn't the development that's a problem - with the Web Platform Installer I could be up and running in minutes... My main concern is the performance hit that's taken by hitting a database, or spinning up the ASP.NET framework, to return content that **does not change** and **doesn't need to be versioned**.  Especially when this is hosted on a shared server - I'm really trying for a minimalist approach.