# How to use two (or more) xml files in one xsl document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been struggling for a while to get two (or more) XML files to be processed by the same xsl file.

I followed the steps in this post: [Including an XML file in an XML/XSL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703312/including-an-xml-file-in-an-xml-xsl-file) but I haven't been able to get this to work.

I can't seem to get the file loaded to be processed, no error.

This is the first xm file - Dial_Stats_MWB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UK_Products_Pipeline>
  <LastFinishCode>
    <SiteName>UK</SiteName>
    <LastFinishCode>Agent Logout</LastFinishCode>
    <Numbers>1</Numbers>
  </LastFinishCode>
  <LastFinishCode>
    <SiteName>UK</SiteName>
    <LastFinishCode>Busy</LastFinishCode>
    <Numbers>1</Numbers>
  </LastFinishCode>
  <LastFinishCode>
    <SiteName>UK</SiteName>
    <LastFinishCode>BW Sale</LastFinishCode>
    <Numbers>1</Numbers>
  </LastFinishCode>
</UK_Products_Pipeline>
```

The second file - Dial_Stats_UK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UK_Products_Pipeline>
  <LastFinishCode>
    <SiteName>MWB</SiteName>
    <LastFinishCode>Bearer Capability Not Presently Authorized (ISDN Cause Code 57)</LastFinishCode>
    <Numbers>1</Numbers>
  </LastFinishCode>
  <LastFinishCode>
    <SiteName>MWB</SiteName>
    <LastFinishCode>Confirmed Booking</LastFinishCode>
    <Numbers>1</Numbers>
  </LastFinishCode>
  <LastFinishCode>
    <SiteName>MWB</SiteName>
    <LastFinishCode>Lost</LastFinishCode>
    <Numbers>1</Numbers>
  </LastFinishCode>
</UK_Products_Pipeline>
```

And the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> XSLT with XML included </title>
      </head>
      <body style="background-color:lightblue;color:green">
        <table cellSpacing="0" border="1" cellPadding="2">
          <!-- Set Variables -->
          <xsl:variable name="external">
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('D:\DATA\Marquee\dial_stats_UK.xml')/*"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <!-- Process Data Start -->
          <xsl:for-each select="//UK_Products_Pipeline/LastFinishCode">
            <tr>
           <xsl:if test="SiteName ='MWB'">
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="SiteName"/>
             </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="LastFinishCode"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Numbers"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:if>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <!-- Process File Data Start -->
            <xsl:call-template name="ExternalData">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$external"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ExternalData">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:variable name="external">
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('D:\DATA\Marquee\dial_stats_UK.xml')/*"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <table cellSpacing="0" border="1" cellPadding="2" style="background-color:white;color:black">
        <tr>
          <td>
            I do see this.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Process External Data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//UK_Products_Pipeline/LastFinishCode">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="SiteName"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <xsl:if test="SiteName ='UK'">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="SiteName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="LastFinishCode"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Numbers"/>
            </td>
          </xsl:if>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the processing takes place the same file is processed again not the second file.

I don't know whether or not you can give me any suggestions on what I do wrong here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
`<xsl:for-each select="//UK_Products_Pipeline/LastFinishCode">`
```

to

```
`<xsl:for-each select="document('file:///D:/DATA/Marquee/dial_stats_UK.xml')/UK_Products_Pipeline/LastFinishCode">`
```

in the template where you want to process data from the second input file.

Although a cleaner approach is to write matching templates with a mode for the nodes from the second file you want be processed. 
Then you just would do:

```
`<xsl:apply-templates select="document('file:///D:/DATA/Marquee/dial_stats_UK.xml')/UK_Products_Pipeline" mode="my-mode"/>`
```

and your templates for that mode would output the table you want.

Comment: That did solve the problem indeed, I guess my mistake here is that you have to address each location in the file directly, rather than once it is loaded use relative addressing.
Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can use a apply-templates or for-each to ensure the context node is from a secondary input file and then you can use relative paths. Doing a call-template however does not change the context node.

Answer (score 1):

Note that document(), like many other things in the XML family, works on URIs, not Windows filenames. Some implementations of the specs allow you to use a Windows file name in place of a URI, but many don't, so it's best not to rely on it. For example

```
d:\data\marquee\stats.xml
```

is a Windows filename, not a URI. The corresponding URI is

```
file:///d:/data/marquee/stats.xml
```

Comment: Many thanks for that explanation. I need to use a shared directory to pull the file from, would that make it:
    `file:///servername/sharename/stats.xml`
or something different than that?

Comment: If you're using UNC filenames, their mapping to URIs is something of a black art. There's some (empirical) information about UNC filenames and URIs in a previous Saxon release here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/saxon/index.php?title=UNC_filenames but it may not apply to current releases or to other XSLT processors. I think my recommendation would be access the files via HTTP rather than via UNC.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly I'm not in control of the 'SQL' server this comes from and there is no way they allow me to get http installed on there or event to 'add' the directory the file is written to as virtual directory to a remote http server. I'm kind of hands tied here.