# Passing a parameter does not seem to work

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need a parameter to be send to a template to help with processing the right nodes in an external second xml file (this to keep the amount of templates small).

I've found that the following code send the parameter and processes it correctly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
      This is text1
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="my-mode">
        <xsl:with-param name="testParam" select="'TEST_PARAMETER'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      This is text2
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="DialStats" mode="my-mode">
  <xsl:param name="testParam" />
   <br></br>
   This is text 3<br></br>
     <xsl:value-of select="$testParam" /><br></br>
   This is text 4<br></br>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I implement the second file I've found that the following no longer passes the parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  This is text1
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file://D:/DATA/Marquee/DATA/MarqueeStats.xml')" mode="my-mode">
    <xsl:with-param name="testParam" select="'TEST_PARAMETER'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  This is text2
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DialStats" mode="my-mode">
  <xsl:param name="testParam" />
  <br></br>
  This is text 3<br></br>
  <xsl:value-of select="$testParam" /><br></br>
  This is text 4<br></br>
 </xsl:template>
```

It calls the template correctly, as I can see both the lines with 'This is text x". So the parameter is gone. I did find some articles suggesting the match= needs to be set, so I matched that with the xml root:

```
<DialStats>
  <Countries Country="Denmark">
    <Products Product="MR">
    . . .
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

BTW this is just the basics I need to get right as a lot more code need to be added.

Comment: Could you check the line `<xsl:apply-templates select="document mode="my-mode">`? The select attribute cannot be correct. This is not valid XML.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had some issues getting it right when creating the examples.

Comment: I just ran the example with `xsltproc` (using libxml 20901, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815). It worked although I had to remove the `file:` prefix from the filename. I guess `xsltproc` can only handle local files. Which processor do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel and Internet Explorer 6, 8 and 10 I don't know what versions those are.

Comment: the file solution was being suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758481/how-to-use-two-or-more-xml-files-in-one-xsl-document

Comment: The solution offered there specifies the Windows path to be written with _three_ slashes between `file:` and drive letter `d:`. In your code above you use only two. Have you tried with three?

Comment: Yes I used three, two and one but unfortunately none of them worked.