# XML files transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

Background: I have not dealt with a lot of XML processing in my work. However, my current work needs me to read and transform some medium to largish XML files in the order of 10s to 100s of MBs.

Requirement: these XML documents have user IDs that I need to change to fake IDs. These mappings of user to fake IDs are given in a separate file.

What I would do: Conventionally, what I would do is read the whole file in, building a DOM tree, then recursing through the nodes in the tree and changing the user IDs to fake IDs as I go and lastly dumping the whole document out in the end.

My question: is there a cleaner to do this with technologies like XSLT, XPath, etc. than this traditional model? Since I will be developing using the .NET framework, it would be useful though not necessary if I could get an answer in the context of .NET and C#.

Apologies if this sounds like a noob question. I have never worked with XML based technologies in the past. I guess everyone needs to start somewhere and this is my cue! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) might do the trick. With XSLT, you create a style sheet with all your code and the mappings of the user-fake IDs. You'd have a function that applies a replace to all user IDs.

It will require a little work in learning the XSLT way of doing things (XML syntax, a functional paradigm, learn about XPath) but if you have the time it will be useful for this and other XML tasks.

In .net, use the [XSLT reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [transformation classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do your work. Your C# code will be minimal and all your logic will be in your XSL Transform style sheet (.xsl file you pass as a parameter). Remember to use the `XSLCompiledTransform` since it's faster.

Comment: Hi @ArthurChamz- thanks for your answer and the pointers. Like I say in my comment to the answer above, embedding a style sheet with all that data is not possible since there may be 1000s of IDs with new ones being generated from time to time. Something like a callback function in C# that would be called every time a new XML element that matches the template is found is something that would actually suit me better I think. Is something like this possible?

Comment: @Sandman You're welcome. If the IDs generated file is XML, then you can access or "embed" (whatever suits you better) that generated file from your XSL style sheet and, from there, transform another XML. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703312/including-an-xml-file-in-an-xml-xsl-file

Comment: Thanks @ArthurChamz. I'll take a look. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an entirely standard XSL requirement. If you can embed the mapped names into your stylesheet, then you can use the command line [msxsl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=21714) to prototype this. The transform will then, with varying degrees of efficiency, apply the mappings you need to pseudonymise the data.

If the names are all stored in well known elements (or attributes) then start with an identity transform and introduce additional templates to map the names as they appear in the document.

Comment: Hi @Pekka- thanks for your answer. You mention embedding the mapping in the stylesheet; however I don't think that will be possible in my scenario because there may be 1000s of IDs and new ones being generated and added from time to time. I was thinking of something like a callback function in C# that is called every time a new XML element that matches a template is found. This would in some sense help me define transforms where the transform needs to be looked up or computed, like in my case. Do you think XSLT or other related XML technologies could do something like that?

Comment: You can pass in the IDs as a parameter to your stylesheet, keeping them out of static portion of the application. Alternately you can also use the `document()` function, or a CLR extension function.