# Using xslt to alter nodes from a copied xml file

Tags: xslt

I would like to copy and alter data from another xml data. I have in addition to the normal two input xml files an extra xml file. I would like to embed the entire content of this xml file into my output xml and then change some aspect of it. I have managed to do this by copying the entire file into the right area as desired thus (Thanks to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703312/including-an-xml-file-in-an-xml-xsl-file)):

```
<test>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('filename.xml')/*"/>
</test>
```

Problem is, I want to change some of the data in filename and I don't know how I can get this done. Something along this line, perhaps?

```
    <xsl:template match="document('filename.xml')/root/elemntToBeChanged">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Test/changeItToThis"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root"><!--Input document's root element -->
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="*|document('External-Doc.xml')"/></xsl:copy><!--Extrenal document called here -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```